# ObjectiveC Blocks and Variables

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I have the following method that makes a webservice call from my iOS app (using Restkit)...

```
BOOL valid = NO;

RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
NSString *servicePath = [WebServiceHelper pathForServiceOperation:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/security/isSessionValid/%@", username]];
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:servicePath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    BooleanServiceResponse *resp = [mappingResult firstObject];
    valid = resp.value;
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while validating session for user %@ : %@", username, error);
}];

return valid;
```

However, I get an error on the `valid` variable, saying it is declared outside the block and is not assignable.  I Googled around a bit, and found a recommendation that I declare valid like this instead...

```
__block BOOL valid = NO;
```

That gets rid of the error.  However, I find that no matter what I set the `valid` value to within my block, it is not set appropriately when exiting the block.  How can I set this value so my method returns the expected value?

Comment: Ehm, that block is called asynchronously. `valid` is not yet set when it's returned. You have to cope with this. You can't return values from an asynchronous handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't understand how blocks work. It's not a matter of variable visibility, although `__block` is correct.

You block is a function executed asynchronously, so `valid` will be set to `resp.value` whenever that block is executed, which is very likely to happen later than your return statement.

You need to change your design since so far you are returning an object which is not guaranteed to be set.

**EDIT**

Example

```
- (void)didFinishValidation:(BOOL)valid {
   // Do whatever you like with the `valid` value
   if (valid) {
     //...
   } else {
     //...
   }
}
```

and your blocks become

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:servicePath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    BooleanServiceResponse *resp = [mappingResult firstObject];
    valid = resp.value;
    [self didFinishValidation:valid];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while validating session for user %@ : %@", username, error);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Is there a way to wait on a return value somehow?  With most of the calls, it's fine if it executes asynchronously.  With this particular one, though, I'd like to be able to return a YES/NO value right away.  If I add in a loop waiting on a "completed" flag, for example, and then return after I'm sure the webservice call has completed, will that work as expected?

Comment: as I said you need to change the design. I'd make the workflow waiting for the block to execute by delegation. For instance you can implement a method like `- (void)didFinishValidation:(BOOL)valid` that you can call from inside your block

Comment: "You block is a function executed asynchronously" Well, a block is just a callable thing; it can be executed in however way (now, later, never, multiple times, etc.). It is the API he is passing the block to that is executing it asynchronously.

Comment: That's why the word "your" is there.

Answer (score 3):

In general it's required to define variables as __block in order to mutate them from within a block. The problem here is that the "return" is called before the block is called - the best way to handle this situation is not to define this method as - (BOOL)... but as - (void)... and return the result async via delegation or block callback.