# Class method with an NSMutableArray losing its value in a block

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

First thing's first: I'm fairly new to iOS development.

I'm using "RestKit" in an application I'm putting together and I'm encountering an odd situation. I have a class method of which I intend to return an `NSMutableArray`. Below is the method in question:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)
  getGames:(Player *)user
{
  NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"user_id" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", user.user_id]};
  NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"games.json"
                                         parameters:queryParams
                                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                              [returnArray addObjectsFromArray:mappingResult.array];
                                            }
                                            failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                              [returnArray addObjectsFromArray:@[error]];
                                            }];

  return returnArray;
}
```

In the `success` block, if I iterate through every object in the `returnArray`, it gives me the results I want. Same thing goes for failure.

However, if I iterate through the same `returnArray` outside of the block, in the line just above the `return returnArray` statement, it's empty.

Any idea why this is happening? Since `returnArray` is declared in the "`getGames:` method" shouldn't it be accessible outside the success or failure blocks within the method?

Comment: Maybe because it's asynchronous. So The `return` is performed before the block is finished.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObjectiveC Blocks and Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082775/objectivec-blocks-and-variables)

Comment: Agreed. You could have `-getGames:` return `void`, and take a completion block parameter if you want to call back asynchronously.

Comment: That makes sense. It wasn't even occurring to me that this was an asynchronous call. RTFM indeed. Thanks everyone.

Comment: it is not an odd situation, in time you have the content _later_ (via a completion blocks), and you really iterate the `returnArray` _before_ the completion block runs. you just simply no have the details in that particular time when you expected.

Comment: Can somebody (@Larme, @ZevEisenberg) who provided the answer as a comment post it as an answer so the OP can accept it. That will mark the question as answered, AND give you credit for the answer.

Comment: Instead of returning the return array you should consider using a block. (Completion block) since the success/failure is asynchronous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning method object from inside block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22267865/returning-method-object-from-inside-block)